# Фильтр на Laravel

Tags: search, laravel5, filter

Есть фильтр/форма поиска в которой поля: площадь объекта (от, до), стоимость объекта (от, до), стоимость объекта за кв2 (от, до), только актуальные (чекбокс), и кнопка "Найти". В базе: area, price, priceMeter, status - соответственно. В контроллере я получаю данные с формы, с этим все хорошо. **Не могу понять, как будет выглядеть запрос к модели Product, если некоторые поля формы могут остаться пустыми?**

```
$minArea = (int)$request['minArea'] == 0 ? $data->min('area') : $request['minArea'];
$maxArea = (int)$request['maxArea'] == 0 ? $data->max('area') : $request['maxArea'];
$minPrice = (int)$request['minPrice'] == 0 ? $data->min('price') : $request['minPrice'];
$maxPrice = (int)$request['maxPrice'] == 0 ? $data->max('price') : $request['maxPrice'];
$minMetPrice = (int)$request['minMetPrice'] == 0 ? $data->min('costmeter') : $request['minMetPrice'];
$maxMetPrice = (int)$request['maxMetPrice'] == 0 ? $data->max('costmeter') : $request['maxMetPrice'];

$products = Product::where([
     ['area', '>=', $minArea],
     ['area', '<=', $maxArea],
     ['price', '>=', $minPrice],
     ['price', '<=', $maxPrice],
     ['priceMeter', '>=', $minMetPrice],
     ['priceMeter', '<=', $maxMetPrice]
])->get();
```

Пытаюсь делать таким образом, но работает неверно - когда ввожу только maxArea (т.е. Площадь до..) не выводит некоторые результаты, которые больше указанного значения. Помогите пжлста

Answer (score 0):

Там, где пустое значение поля $request, присваивайте переменной соответственно максимальное или минимальное значение из таблицы бд и отправляйте запрос. Например,

```
    if($request['minarea']==null){
    $minarea= DB::table('product')->min('area');
    }
```

Comment: Мне кажется, я так и делаю. У меня просто проверка на null в jquery происходит, перед отправкой в ajax. Странно то, что поля minMetPrice и maxMetPrice отрабатывают правильно, а все остальные либо частично, либо вообще ничего не выводят, хотя данные точно есть